# PHP $_SESSION variable not saving across pages

Tags: php, html, api, session-variables

I've been having some big problems with this all day.

I'm trying to save a SESSION variable and then print it onto another PHP file however the variable isn't saving across pages. I'm essentailly making a login system using SQL to then be able to view the users details using the username as the SESSION variable.

I've done a lot of research and it seems that my redirect URL is causing the issue. It needs to be a realtive URL used not a HTTP one as this doesn't carry over SESSION variables.

I've tested that the variable is stored by printing it straight away in the source PHP file and that works fine. It just doesn't get transfered across, it comes back with a blank array.

I'm calling my method from an API routes PHP file. I don't think this causes an issue?

Here is my setup:

API PHP file:

```
app->post('/api/customer/login/{Username}/{PassW}', function(Request $request, Response $response){
    $Username = $request->getParam('Username');
    $PassW = $request->getParam('PassW');

    $PassW = md5($PassW);//FIND NEW WAY OF HASHING AS MD5 IS DEPRECIATED
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE Username= '$Username' AND PassW='$PassW' LIMIT 1";

    try{
        $db = new db();
        $db = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(count($result) == 1){
        session_start();      
        $_SESSION['Username'] = $Username;


       echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Correct!');
       window.location.href='http://localhost/testing/yourprofile.php';
       </script>";
        exit();
```

Test SESSION variable has been set PHP file:

```
<?php

session_start();
print_r($_SESSION); 
?>
```

I'm very new to all this so my apologies if it's something very simple for you guys.

Big Love.

Comment: `sesssion_start()` needs to be in the beginning of the file. also in API PHP file. Or at least before outputting anything to the browser.

Comment: What framework are you using, I'm curious about this `->post('/api/customer/login/{Username}/{PassW}`

Comment: It’s called Slim PHP framework

Comment: That was what I thought, thanks, I've never used it but I've seen it before.  It's similar looking to the framework I'm building. AKA, it's event driven.

Comment: Any idea on what my issue could be?

Comment: Yep, probably your if condition before `session_start` is failing and so you never call it.  This is why it's recommend to put that before anything else.  `md5($PassW);` this is bad, and some of your login logic is flawed.  use `password_hash` and `password_verify` and dont query using the password.

Comment: It can’t be failing because it redirects me to the php page in the statement

Comment: from all that nasty JS at the bottom you mean.... I would use `header('location: '.$url); exit()`  The problem with JS is you could be caching the page in the browser.

Comment: Yes sorry I know about my password issues.. it’s not the most important project and as I said I’m new so I’m still learning .. but yes from my terrible JS ... I’ll try that

Comment: Where is the rest of the code, the part where the `catch block` is at, if you get an exception in there it will bail out.  And I cant see what happens then.  MD5 is junk, I just brute forced one yesterday in about 12 second for another question (aka I cheated on it)  It had to do with finding an anagram that produced a given hash, so I just brute forced the hash instead...  It was easy with knowing what characters were used, just took a few million iterations in a loop.  Also SHA1 is faster then MD5

Comment: Hmmm I don’t like copying in loads of code but yes there is a catch block there .. that’s a good point, I’ll look into that too Phoenix

Comment: Ok ok I get your point! I’ll make it more secure!

Answer (score 0):

I have finally sorted it!

I needed to get the session ID first.

Hopefully this will help anyone in the future with this issue

Please see solution below:

PHP Page One:

```
session_start();  
        $_SESSION['Username'] = $Username;
        header("Location: http://localhost/testing/yourprofile.php?PHPSESSID=".session_id());
        exit();
```

PHP Page Two (Test):

```
<?php
session_id($_GET['PHPSESSID']);
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

Thanks to Phoenix for sorting my other issues! :)

Answer (score -1):

I did what I could to fix and clean up your code.  I don't know if it will fix the session issues, but you should be calling session_start much sooner then you are.

```
app->post('/api/customer/login/{Username}/{PassW}', function(Request $request, Response $response){
    session_start(); //<-- put this here or (just put in index.php)
    $Username = $request->getParam('Username');
    $PassW = $request->getParam('PassW');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE Username = :username";

    try{
        $db = new db();
        $db = $db->connect();
         ///prepare the query
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
         /// execute the query 
        $stmt->execute([':username'=>$Username]);   
        ///get the result, our usernames are unique in the DB
        //so there is no need to limit them or count
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //result is an array or boolean false.
        if(!$result){
            //check the password
            if(password_verify($PassW, $result['PassW'])){ 
                $_SESSION['Username'] = $Username;
                //redirect, do not output ANYTHING before doing this
                header('Location: http://localhost/testing/yourprofile.php');
                exit();

            }
```

Notes/Updates

- Use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to hash passwords (it's pretty much the standard these days)
- Use prepared statements, thankfully your using PDO (which is what I have used the last 4 years).  I used to use Mysqli, but I found PDO much easier, and with better overall functionality.  So you will see where I used `:username` as a named placeholder, instead of the value and then the value goes in an array with the same key(I think the `:` in the data array is optional with certain settings turned on, but I always just put it in), and then you execute it and that's it.
- The `Username` field in the Database should be a Unique Index. This way it's impossible to put duplicate usernames in, the database wont let you.  This simplifies what we need to do in PHP because we can rely on that and don't need to check as much stuff.
- When checking passwords you can use [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).  The first argument is the incoming password from the user.  It doesn't need to be encrypted or anything.  One of the reasons it's designed that way is you shouldn't really be searching with the password as part of the condition.  Because then you are relying on the case-insensitive search of the database for verifying the hash, which it was not built to do. There are various other reasons for using password_verify besides that, but one could write a whole post on just the intricacy of cryptological hashing and comparison.

But I think that is enough for now.

Comment: Thank you so much Phoenix, you didn’t have to do this for me.. but thank you :’)

Comment: Phoenix, me again. I've changed the code to yours and have now hashed my passwords when user registers however the IF statement isn't firing. It's coming through with my else statement saying "Incorrect Login"... Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, I have `$username` it should be `$Username`, sorry I'll update the answer. Variables are case sensitive,  right here `$stmt->execute([':username'=>$username]);`